# convert .spd file to pdf file

Tags: java, android, pdf, file-conversion

I have an .spd file and I want to convert it to pdf file, I looked for libraries  over web but couldn't find any.

Actually, my android app gives me spd and jpg file. I am able to convert from jpg to pdf but it takes a lot of time and I also used different libraries for that but got same time for that process. So I switched to convert spd to pdf file, but I am not able to locate any java based library for that.

It would be great if anyone could suggest any library or something.

Thanks

Comment: provide sample of your .sdp file if you can

Comment: @KishanCS, It is a file generated by samsung s-pen sdk.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I have the same exact problem -- several (now old) SPD files, no way to convert them to PDF. The links provided in @KishanCS answer have now expired/are no longer valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension of SPen's files is indeed .spd. I'm afraid that there is currently no official MIME type associated with .spd files.

You can find offical MIME types in the IANA's MIME Media Types register: `http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types`

This might help you:

- Go to http://developer.samsung.com/samsung-mobile-sdk/sdk Download
  the SDK
- Inside the binaries there are some programming guides as mentionned
  in 1.3 at http://developer.samsung.com/samsung-mobile-sdk
- Have a look to ProgrammingGuide_Pen.pdf
- See quote like : The sample application saves the data created with
  the Pen package in a file. The application supports the SPD format
  for Pen data files and the +SPD data format (image file with added
  SPD data) for general image files.

Comment: Thanks. It is really helpful.